# What can we call a job position who handle inquiries?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

I have visa consultancy firm with a team who handle all inquiries on phone. They take requirements of the client, note down and also consult sometimes with the help of consultants.
What can we call a job position who handle inquiries? I thought of this 'Inquiry Handler' but I think it doesn't sound good for on-paper designation. Can you suggest something better?

Example sentence:

> The firm employs twenty *{Inquiry Handlers}* who take phone calls from clients, noting down their requirements and helping them (sometimes with the assistance of consultants).

Comment: You need to include an example sentence, where you would use this word, or your question will likely be closed @Datt.

Comment: @Gary I can't think of example sentence. I just need better word or phrase for the mentioned job position.

Comment: Customer Service Representative.  Customer Care Specialist/Professional

Comment: Are you talking about telephone operators / receptionists, or requirements analysis and the like?

Answer (score 1):

It´s a part of the "Customer Relations Management" and it is called client-service. Inqueries of all kind will be handled instantly or forwarded to the appropriate department. Even inhouse or internal enquiries could be handled depending on the amount of requests.